# How do I install ClamAV without internet in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: clamav

How i can install ClamAV offline in Ubuntu system as I know how to update the binaries but the problem here is the version got changed and I need to update the ClamAV version before updating the database offline. Please let me know how I can do this if anyone have clear knowledge on ClamAV offline installation.

Comment: The current Ubuntu 18.04 is 18.04.4, so if your system reports 18.04.2 you have a system that is missing updates since before 8-Aug-2019 (the date of the 18.04.3 ISO release, installed systems upgraded to that earlier though - http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/) so you'll be missing many packages starting with https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/clamav and it's dependencies, each dependency may require it's own like set...  You're months behind on upgrades if using 18.04.2 so compare what you have installed with that list..

Comment: The problem is i dont have internet in the network so i have to do everything through offline. My question was how i can install or update clam-av version.

Comment: I would just make/[clone] an equivalent VM of what you have, run it on a machine that is online and have it fully-upgrade, then use those packages (transferred by thumb-drive) to your offline system.  ie. upgrade the whole system and not just the minimal packages; as almost any thumb-drive found will have enough space to allow for all packages and not just minimal.